# High CPU during pymysql IO

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I am trying to debug high CPU usage on a mostly IO bound python application. The python application polls for messages from a queue, performs a bunch of MySQL queries and an external API call. It's not multi-threaded and we spawn multiple python processes (about 4x number of cores) to achieve parallelism. The multi-process app ends up consuming 90%+ CPU under load (when there are ample messages in the queue). Upon profiling the app, it seems to suggest that most CPU is consumed while pymsql writes or reads from socket. Is there a way to optimize pymysql to consume less CPU? Can it do zero copy I/O? Or is it acceptable for pymysql to consume high amount of CPU during I/O?

[image: profiling]

Environment:
python 3.7.7
pymysql 0.7.11
mysql 5.7

Comment: You can try setting  part of the MySQL session to read only [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html)

Comment: Sorry, not sure how that will help with CPU utilisation in the python side?